# Itunes Connect vs Apple Developer

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am listed as admin on apple developer Team portal for my organization, we created one app, signed it and trying to export for Enterprise deployment but it asking for itunes connect account.

What is missing do we need something else in addition to apple developer program? please guide.

I tried same Id of developer program to login to itunes connect but it says to enroll. So confused :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your team agent needs to add you to the iTunes Connect Team, too. This is not the same user management as in the Developer Member Center.

In iTunes Connect, you will at least need the "Technical" role to deploy your app.